# UNION OR UNION ALL MYSQL OPTIMIZATION

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to optimize the MySQL query below to no avail. It currently takes up to 3 seconds to execute:

```
select count( DISTINCT v.id) from 
( 
    select sub_jobs.id from sub_jobs, main_jobs where sub_jobs.title LIKE '%abc%' and main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id 

    UNION ALL 

    select sub_jobs.id from sub_jobs, main_jobs where job_title LIKE '%abc%' and main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id 

    UNION ALL 

    select sub_jobs.id from sub_jobs, main_jobs, companies where companies.company_name LIKE '%abc%' and main_jobs.company_id=companies.id and main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id 
) 
as v
```

**What do I want to do:**

- Search three columns in 3 tables for a keyword and return the distinct count

**Basic table structure:**

*1. sub_jobs*

- id
- title [i want to search this column]
- parent_id

*2. main_jobs*

- id
- job_title  [i want to search this column]
- company_id [some rows don't have an entry for this column]

*3. companies*

- id
- company_name  [i want to search this column]

EXPLAIN

```
------column titles------

id
select_type:
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra

--- row 1 ----

id:  1
select_type: PRIMARY
table: <derived2>
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
102642
NULL


---- row 2 ----

id: 2
select_type: DERIVED
table: main_jobs
index
PRIMARY,id_index,id_industry_featured_index
id_index
4
NULL
34214
Using index


---- row 3 ----

id: 2
select_type: DERIVED
table: sub_jobs
ref
parent_id,parent_id_category_index
parent_id
4
myjobmag_myjobdb.main_jobs.id
1
Using where


---- row 4 ----

id: 3
select_type: UNION
table: main_jobs
ALL
PRIMARY,id_index,id_industry_featured_index
NULL
NULL
NULL
34214
Using where

---- row 5 ----

id: 3
select_type: UNION
table: sub_jobs
ref
parent_id,parent_id_category_index
parent_id
4
main_jobs.id
1
Using index

---- row 6 ----


id: 4
select_type: UNION
table: main_jobs
ALL
PRIMARY,id_index,id_industry_featured_index
NULL
NULL
NULL
34214
NULL

---- row 7 ----

id: 4
select_type: UNION
table: companies
eq_ref
PRIMARY
PRIMARY
4
main_jobs.company_id
1
Using where


---- row 8 ----

id: 4
select_type: UNION
table: sub_jobs
ref
parent_id,parent_id_category_index
parent_id
4
main_jobs.id
1
Using index


---- row 9 ----

id: NULL
select_type: UNION RESULT
table: <union2,3,4>
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
Using temporary
```

I have tried using UNION without the DISTINCT with no significant gains.

How can I reduce the runtime of this query.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reduce one condition. Please try and let me know

```
select count( DISTINCT v.id) from 
( 
    select sub_jobs.id 
    from sub_jobs inner join main_jobs
    on main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id  
    where (sub_jobs.title LIKE '%abc%' OR job_title LIKE '%abc%') 

    UNION ALL 

    select sub_jobs.id 
    from sub_jobs, main_jobs, companies
    where companies.company_name LIKE '%abc%' and
          main_jobs.company_id=companies.id and 
          main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id 
) 
as v
```

**edit after question update**

It is possible to combine 2 queries like this :

```
select count( DISTINCT v.id) from 
( 
    select sub_jobs.id 
    from sub_jobs 
         inner join main_jobs
          on main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id 
         inner join companies 
          on main_jobs.company_id=companies.id
    where companies.company_name LIKE '%abc%'
          OR
          sub_jobs.title LIKE '%abc%' 
          OR 
          job_title LIKE '%abc%'       
) 
as v
```

Let me know if it is working or throws error

Comment: Thank you for your help. No visible change.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a single quert with or instead of the 3 query with union

but you should take a look at explain plan

```
    select count(dictinnct sub_jobs.id )
    from sub_jobs
    INNER JOIN main_jobs on main_jobs.id=sub_jobs.parent_id 
    INNER JOIN companies on main_jobs.company_id=companies.id
    where companies.company_name LIKE '%abc%' 
    OR main_jobs.job_title LIKE '%abc%'
    OR sub_jobs.title LIKE '%abc%'
```